# Discord.js | Command Cooldown is set but not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So the message.js where the cooldown go and help.js is a command, `help` command is currently set to `60 seconds` as can you see at the `cooldown` but no matter what I input there it doesn't work and still set to less than `1` second I guess for the output kindly check the `GIF` included to this question.

[image]

**message.js:**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const settings = require("../../config/settings.json");

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const prefixesdatabase = client.settings.ensure(message.guild.id, settings);

    if (!client.settings.get(message.guild.id, "prefix")) {
        client.settings.set(message.guild.id, {
            prefix: settings.prefix
        });
    }

    if (message.content.match(new RegExp(`^<@!?${client.user.id}>( |)$`))) {
        message.reply(`my prefix is: \`${prefixesdatabase.prefix}\``);
    }

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefixesdatabase.prefix)) return;
    const command = message.content
        .split(" ")[0]
        .slice(prefixesdatabase.prefix.length);
    const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 2) * 1000;
    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 2000;
            return message.reply(
                `Before using **${
                    prefixesdatabase.prefix
                }${command}**, please wait for **${timeLeft.toFixed(
                    1
                )} second for cooldowns!**`
            );
        }
    }
    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
    let cmd;
    if (client.commands.has(command)) {
        cmd = client.commands.get(command);
    } else if (client.aliases.has(command)) {
        cmd = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(command));
    }
    try {
        cmd.run(client, message, args);
    } catch (e) {
        return console.log(`Invalid command: ${command}`);
    } finally {
        console.log(
            `${message.author.username} using command ${prefixesdatabase.prefix}${command}`
        );
    }
};
```

**help.js**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const settings = require("../../config/settings.json");
    const prefixesdatabase = client.settings.ensure(message.guild.id, settings);

    const helpArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const helpArgs = helpArray.slice(1);

    if (!helpArgs[0]) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#b491c8")
            .setDescription(
                `**My prefix:** \`${prefixesdatabase.prefix}\` , Slash Commands list for \`/help\`\nClick [HERE](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${client.user.id}&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands) to invite me to your server.`
            )
            .addField("**:gear: Basic**", "`help`, `ping`, `vote`, `uptime`, `setprefix`")
            .addField(
                "**️ Moderation**",
                "`ban`, `clear`, `clearwarn`, `createchannel`, `createemoji`, `kick`, `lockchannel`, `mute`, `rename`, `slowmode`, `unban`, `unlockchannel`, `unmute`, `warn`, `warnings`"
            )           
            .addField(
                "**⚙ Utility**",
                "`aes256`, `avatar`, `channel`, `embed`, `roleinfo`, `reverse`, `setafk`, `snipe`, `stats`, `timer`, `translate`, `whois`, `weather`, `youtube`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:magic_wand: Pruning**",
                "`urole`, `unorole`, `krole`, `knorole`, `fetch`"
            )           
            .addField(
                "**:tada: Giveaways**",
                "`start-giveaway`, `reroll`, `end-giveaway`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:frame_photo: Images**",
                "`captcha`, `circle`, `delete`, `gay`, `changemymind`, `trigger`, `clyde`, `petpet`, `magik`, `iphonex`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:musical_note: Music**",
                "`play`, `stop`, `skip`, `queue`, `autoplay`, `loop`, `volume`, `pause`, `resume`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:partying_face: Fun**",
                "`8ball`, `cat`, `deaes256`, `kiss`, `meme`, `ngif`, `pat`, `poke`, `smug`, `thigh`, `tickle`"
            )           
            .addFields(
                { name: ':desktop: Github (Source Code)', value: 'https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot' },
                { name: ':revolving_hearts: Support the Developer:', value: 'https://ko-fi.com/mashwishi' }   
              )         
            .setTitle('Prune Bot | Commands')
            .setFooter(`©${nowyear} ${client.user.username} Created by Mashwishi.\nCommand requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, `https://i.imgur.com/ypxq7B9.png`)
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/ypxq7B9.png')    
            .setAuthor('Join our Discord Server', 'https://i.imgur.com/hKeHeEy.gif', 'https://discord.io/LIMYAW');
        message.channel.send({ embed });
    }

    if (helpArgs[0]) {
        let command = helpArgs[0];

        if (client.commands.has(command)) {
            command = client.commands.get(command);
            let alia = command.help.aliases;
            if (command.help.aliases < 1) alia = "No aliases";

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(
                    `Command: ${command.help.name}`,
                    client.user.displayAvatarURL()
                )
                .setDescription(
                    `
            **Description:**\n\`\`\`${
                            command.help.description ||
                            "There is no Description for this command."
                        }\`\`\`\n**Usage:**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.help.usage || "No Usage"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Permissions:**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.help.accessableby || "Members"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Cooldown (in seconds):**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.help.cooldown || "No Cooldown"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Aliases:**\n\`\`\`${alia}\`\`\``
                    
                )
                .setColor("#4a4b4d")
                .setFooter(
                    `© ${nowyear} ${client.user.username} | This command requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`
                );

            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            const embeds = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`${emojis.cross} Command is not found!`)
                .setColor("RED");

            return message.channel.send(embeds);
        }
    }
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "help",
    description: "This command is used for displaying all commands.",
    usage: "p!help",
    accessableby: "Members",
    aliases: ['?', 'commands', 'command'],
    cooldown: 60
};
```

Comment: Where do you use / assign the command's `help` info that you export inside of your `help.js`? If `message` is an instance of [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) then `message.content` is a [`String`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) and so your `command`.

Comment: i have `command.js` file https://pastebin.com/0GXWj0Np

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `message.js`, you probably confused `command` with the exported command object (from `help.js` for example). Use better variable naming, like `commandText` so it is clear, that it is a text/string.

Your command object is `cmd`, which you use to execute the command using the exported function `.run()`. The `cmd` also contains `.help` property, which has the `.cooldown` property you want.

Here look at a simple example, how I would handle this problem.

```js
// ... Somewhere in the code (probably index.js or main.js) ...

client.commands = new Map();
client.aliases = new Map();

// ... Inside of your command handler (command.js) ...

// The command variable defined as a require of command file (for example help.js)

client.commands.set(command.help.name, command);
command.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
    client.aliases.set(alias, command.help.name);
});

// ... Inside of your message handler (message.js) ...

let commandText = message.content.split(" ")[0].slice(prefixesdatabase.prefix.length);
if (!client.commands.has(commandText)) {
    commandText = client.aliases.get(commandText);
    if (!commandText) return;
}

const command = client.commands.get(commandText);
const cooldownAmount = (command.help.cooldown || 2) * 1000;

// ... Rest of your code ...
```

Note that we use `command.help.cooldown` not `command.cooldown` or `command.name`, etc. Because the exported object itself doesn't have such properties. You added a property `.help` to the exported object using `module.exports.help = { ... }`, which contains the `name` and `cooldown`, etc.

To implement my solution into your code you need to replace the following (inside `message.js`):

```js
// ... Rest of your code ...

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefixesdatabase.prefix)) return;

let commandText = message.content.split(" ")[0].slice(prefixesdatabase.prefix.length);
if (!client.commands.has(commandText)) {
    commandText = client.aliases.get(commandText);
    if (!commandText) return;
}

const command = client.commands.get(commandText);
const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

if (!cooldowns.has(command.help.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.help.name, new Discord.Collection());
}

const now = Date.now();
const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.help.name);
const cooldownAmount = (command.help.cooldown || 2) * 1000;
if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
    if (now < expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
        return message.reply(
            `Before using **${
                prefixesdatabase.prefix
            }${commandText}**, please wait for **${timeLeft.toFixed(
                1
            )} second for cooldowns!**`
        );
    }
}

timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

try {
    command.run(client, message, args);
} catch (e) {
    return console.log(`Invalid command: ${commandText}`);
} finally {
    console.log(
        `${message.author.username} using command ${prefixesdatabase.prefix}${commandText}`
    );
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you help me applying it, I tried to apply things i see from the code block but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can push request to my github project called [PruneBot](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot). `message.js` at `event/client/message.js` and `help.js` at `command/info/help.js`.

Comment: I already have this in command.js
`command.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
    client.aliases.set(alias, command.help.name);
});`

Comment: @Mashwishi I have updated my answer, you can take a look at that. :)

Answer (score 0):

In **help.js** you have `cooldown` inside `module.exports.help` not `module.exports`

You either take it out to a normal `module.exports` or change in **message.js** from

```js
const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 2) * 1000;
```

to

```js
const cooldownAmount = (command.help.cooldown || 2) * 1000;
```

What I said about changing `module.exports.help` to `module.exports` I meant this:

**help.js**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const settings = require("../../config/settings.json");
    const prefixesdatabase = client.settings.ensure(message.guild.id, settings);

    const helpArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const helpArgs = helpArray.slice(1);

    if (!helpArgs[0]) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#b491c8")
            .setDescription(
                `**My prefix:** \`${prefixesdatabase.prefix}\` , Slash Commands list for \`/help\`\nClick [HERE](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${client.user.id}&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands) to invite me to your server.`
            )
            .addField("**:gear: Basic**", "`help`, `ping`, `vote`, `uptime`, `setprefix`")
            .addField(
                "**️ Moderation**",
                "`ban`, `clear`, `clearwarn`, `createchannel`, `createemoji`, `kick`, `lockchannel`, `mute`, `rename`, `slowmode`, `unban`, `unlockchannel`, `unmute`, `warn`, `warnings`"
            )           
            .addField(
                "**⚙ Utility**",
                "`aes256`, `avatar`, `channel`, `embed`, `roleinfo`, `reverse`, `setafk`, `snipe`, `stats`, `timer`, `translate`, `whois`, `weather`, `youtube`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:magic_wand: Pruning**",
                "`urole`, `unorole`, `krole`, `knorole`, `fetch`"
            )           
            .addField(
                "**:tada: Giveaways**",
                "`start-giveaway`, `reroll`, `end-giveaway`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:frame_photo: Images**",
                "`captcha`, `circle`, `delete`, `gay`, `changemymind`, `trigger`, `clyde`, `petpet`, `magik`, `iphonex`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:musical_note: Music**",
                "`play`, `stop`, `skip`, `queue`, `autoplay`, `loop`, `volume`, `pause`, `resume`"
            )
            .addField(
                "**:partying_face: Fun**",
                "`8ball`, `cat`, `deaes256`, `kiss`, `meme`, `ngif`, `pat`, `poke`, `smug`, `thigh`, `tickle`"
            )           
            .addFields(
                { name: ':desktop: Github (Source Code)', value: 'https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot' },
                { name: ':revolving_hearts: Support the Developer:', value: 'https://ko-fi.com/mashwishi' }   
              )         
            .setTitle('Prune Bot | Commands')
            .setFooter(`©${nowyear} ${client.user.username} Created by Mashwishi.\nCommand requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, `https://i.imgur.com/ypxq7B9.png`)
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/ypxq7B9.png')    
            .setAuthor('Join our Discord Server', 'https://i.imgur.com/hKeHeEy.gif', 'https://discord.io/LIMYAW');
        message.channel.send({ embed });
    }

    if (helpArgs[0]) {
        let command = helpArgs[0];

        if (client.commands.has(command)) {
            command = client.commands.get(command);
            let alia = command.aliases;
            if (command.aliases < 1) alia = "No aliases";

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(
                    `Command: ${command.name}`,
                    client.user.displayAvatarURL()
                )
                .setDescription(
                    `
            **Description:**\n\`\`\`${
                            command.description ||
                            "There is no Description for this command."
                        }\`\`\`\n**Usage:**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.usage || "No Usage"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Permissions:**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.accessableby || "Members"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Cooldown (in seconds):**\n\`\`\`${
                        command.cooldown || "No Cooldown"
                    }\`\`\`\n**Aliases:**\n\`\`\`${alia}\`\`\``
                    
                )
                .setColor("#4a4b4d")
                .setFooter(
                    `© ${nowyear} ${client.user.username} | This command requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`
                );

            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            const embeds = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`${emojis.cross} Command is not found!`)
                .setColor("RED");

            return message.channel.send(embeds);
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "This command is used for displaying all commands.",
    usage: "p!help",
    accessableby: "Members",
    aliases: ['?', 'commands', 'command'],
    cooldown: 60
};
```